# How to resize a surface in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

How can I resize a `Surface` object in Pygame? Is there a way to bind a surface object into a `Rect` object, so that resizing the rect would also resize the surface (with `Rect.inflate_ip` method for an example)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this automatically, so if you want some sort of automation for the surface rescaling, you'd need to write your own wrapper class around `pygame.Rect`, that owns a rectangle, and takes in a surface, and resizes the surface when a method of the wrapper is called.

The resizing function you are looking for is [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale). Pass it a surface and the new size you want, and it will return a new surface, or place the result into an already created surface (this is faster).

Comment: Is `scale` method not only for resizing of images at the toplevel? Is it ok to use it continuously (say by setting a timer) to resize many surfaces in the main loop?

Comment: You can use it wherever, just note that it can be a bit slow, but that is unavoidable with a software renderer like pygame.